# How to Crop Multiple Uploads with Image Preview in Laravel 9?

Tags: repository-pattern, laravel-9

I'm attempting to create a form in Laravel 9 (Repository pattern) that allows me to upload multiple images and preview them before allowing the user to crop the image and save both files (original and cropped).

**Do you have any suggestions for how to approach this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you would need a combination of frontend javascript and fileupload on the laravel side. For javascript, you can look at [filepond](https://pqina.nl/filepond/).

Alternatively, you can look at laravel [filament](https://filamentphp.com/). Filament is already using filepond as part of its form builder. It allows multiple files upload and resizing. Maybe you can start your approach from there.